# Accessing Linux host from Windows machine

Tags: linux, dns, ip, redhat, hostname

How to access a web application hosted in Linux machine using host name from Windows 7 client machine instead accessing through IP address?

I just added the Linux machine in to the LAN. So the application is accessible as `http://<IPADDRESS OF Linux Machine>:8080/webapp/index.html`.

However, I want to access by hostname like `http://<hostname>:8080` instead of `http://<IPADDRESS>:8080`. Added the host name of linux machine into 
the DNS server but that didn't help.

Note: The Linux machine (Redhat 5.3) is running under the DNS server (Windows server 2008).

Comment: One of IP address or machine name in necessary to access the machine. How can a client find a machine to be accessed without them as like as http://:8080.

Comment: @Fumu 7, sorry, it was a formatting issue. Please see the updated/edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 ways to solve this issue:

1. If this machine will be definitive, you want to add the hostname in your DNS server.
2. If this machine will be used to test, or temporary activity, you can add de hostname in the windows hosts file, using [this manual](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/).

Just add in the end of file the line like this:  
e.g.:

```
192.168.1.10 srv01.local.br srv01
```

Comment: We have tried adding hostname to our DNS server.But unable to resolve.  We can take your second suggestion, but we want a permanent solution for this issue.We have more than 100 windows client in our LAN network. So it looks bit difficult for us. Kindly let us know if you have any other suggestions.